# file named as "Untitled" when uploaded on Google Drive using Google Drive API v3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file on Google Drive using Google Drive API v3 in JavaScript.
It works but once my file is uploaded on the Google Drive, his name is "Untitled".

I went on many Stack Overflow threads and forums but i don't find an answer because many peoples use Google Drive API v3 with Node.JS, PHP or Python but not with JavaScript.

I think i need to add data to `formData` var but i don't know the name of the data. I already try with `title` and `name`.

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Upload to Drive</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="sign-in-or-out-button" style="margin-left: 25px">Sign In/Authorize</button>
  <button id="revoke-access-button" style="display: none; margin-left: 25px">Revoke access</button>
  <div id="auth-status" style="display: inline; padding-left: 25px"></div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <input id="files" type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
    <button id="upload">Upload</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script src="./jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var GoogleAuth;
  var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
  let access_token = null;

  function handleClientLoad() {
    // Load the API's client and auth2 modules.
    // Call the initClient function after the modules load.
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }

  function initClient() {
    // In practice, your app can retrieve one or more discovery documents.
    var discoveryUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest';

    // Initialize the gapi.client object, which app uses to make API requests.
    // Get API key and client ID from API Console.
    // 'scope' field specifies space-delimited list of access scopes.
    gapi.client.init({
      'apiKey': 'AIzaSyBYf75HczHEqCJpQ97tGPOCxybwZFw0gpA',
      'clientId': '514528342395-in4priacg29o4vqfqdc9bcjnj0d1c1oj.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'discoveryDocs': [discoveryUrl],
      'scope': SCOPE
    }).then(function () {
      GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
      var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();

      setSigninStatus();

      // Call handleAuthClick function when user clicks on
      //      "Sign In/Authorize" button.
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').click(function () {
        handleAuthClick();
      });
      $('#revoke-access-button').click(function () {
        revokeAccess();
      });
    });
  }

  function handleAuthClick() {
    if (GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
      // User is authorized and has clicked "Sign out" button.
      GoogleAuth.signOut();
    } else {
      // User is not signed in. Start Google auth flow.
      GoogleAuth.signIn();
    }
  }

  function revokeAccess() {
    GoogleAuth.disconnect();
  }

  function setSigninStatus() {
    var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
    var isAuthorized = user.hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE);
    if (isAuthorized) {
      access_token = user.xc.access_token;
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign out');
      $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
      $('#seeGapi').css('display', 'inline-block');
      $('#auth-status').html('You are currently signed in and have granted ' +
        'access to this app.');
    } else {
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign In/Authorize');
      $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'none');
      $('#auth-status').html('You have not authorized this app or you are ' +
        'signed out.');
    }
  }

  function updateSigninStatus() {
    setSigninStatus();
  }


  // UPLOAD TO DRIVE SECTION
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const code = urlParams.get('code');
  const redirect_uri = "http://localhost:5500" // replace with your redirect_uri;
  const client_secret = "aHgsCY5LUfssabvl5w6Qqtw9"; // replace with your client secret
  const scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
  // var access_token = "";
  var client_id = "514528342395-in4priacg29o4vqfqdc9bcjnj0d1c1oj.apps.googleusercontent.com" // replace it with your client id;

  function stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(url) {
    return url.split("?")[0].split("#")[0];
  }

  var Upload = function (file) {
    this.file = file;
  };

  Upload.prototype.getType = function () {
    localStorage.setItem("type", this.file.type);
    return this.file.type;
  };
  Upload.prototype.getSize = function () {
    localStorage.setItem("size", this.file.size);
    return this.file.size;
  };
  Upload.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.file.name;
  };
  Upload.prototype.doUpload = function () {
    var that = this;
    var formData = new FormData();

    // add assoc key values, this will be posts values
    formData.append("file", this.file, this.getName());
    formData.append("upload_file", true);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend: function (request) {
        // request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + access_token);

      },
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files",
      data: {
        uploadType: "media"
      },
      xhr: function () {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (myXhr.upload) {
          myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', that.progressHandling, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
      async: true,
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      timeout: 60000
    });
  };

  Upload.prototype.progressHandling = function (event) {
    var percent = 0;
    var position = event.loaded || event.position;
    var total = event.total;
    var progress_bar_id = "#progress-wrp";
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
      percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
    }
    // update progressbars classes so it fits your code
    $(progress_bar_id + " .progress-bar").css("width", +percent + "%");
    $(progress_bar_id + " .status").text(percent + "%");
  };

  $("#upload").on("click", function (e) {
    var file = $("#files")[0].files[0];
    var upload = new Upload(file);

    // maby check size or type here with upload.getSize() and upload.getType()

    // execute upload
    upload.doUpload();
  });
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

I know it's not a perfect code but i need to successfully set a name to the file before beautify the code.

I hope some one can help.

Have a good day :)

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#node.js its untitled because your not sending the metadata in the post body.

Comment: In the body the metadata must come first and must have a `Content-Type` header set to `application/json; charset=UTF-8`. Add the file's metadata in JSON format. Media must come second and must have a `Content-Type` header of any MIME type. Add the file's data to the media part. - this is from the docs linked by DalmTo in the HTTP section, as it seems that you are making an HTTP request using jquery. Is that right?

Comment: Hi DalmTo,
Yes i already consulted the documentation but i don't find any example for JavaScript.

Comment: Hi iansedano,
Yes i'm doing an ajax request with jquery.
Have you an example of the request i should do to make it work ?

Comment: Hav you an idea of what i need to put int the header (before request) to set a name for the file ?
i change that in my code 
`beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + access_token, "title", "myFileName");
},`
but it didn't work.